# paypal "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, paypal

I create an app with MERN stack and I want to make order and to pay with paypal. I have account in Paypal and added secret keys in my app. And now I have a problem :

```
     POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders 400

{name: "INVALID_REQUEST",…}
debug_id
: 
"f1021698a6a86"
details
: 
[{field: "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount/value", value: "", location: "body",…}]
links
: 
[{href: "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER",…}]
message
: 
"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema."
name
: 
"INVALID_REQUEST"
```

Can you help me ?

I show my code below:
In OrderScreen.js file I added details for order and put the paypal button there. So user can see what he pay.

**OrderScreen.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { getError } from '../utils';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import {PayPalButtons, usePayPalScriptReducer} from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, order: action.payload, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'PAY_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: true };
    case 'PAY_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: true };
    case 'PAY_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false };
    case 'PAY_RESET':
      return { ...state, loadingPay: false, successPay: false };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default function OrderScreen() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;

  const params = useParams();
  const { id: orderId } = params;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {
    cart: { carOrderInfo},
} = state;

  const [{isPending}, paypalDispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

  const [
    {
      loading,
      error,
      order,
      successPay,
      loadingPay,
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    order: {},
    error: '',
    successPay: false,
    loadingPay: false,
  });

 

  function createOrder(data, actions) {
    return actions.order
      .create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: { value: order.totalPrice },
          },
        ],
      })
      .then((orderID) => {
        return orderID;
      });
  }

  function onApprove(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(async function (details) {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.put(
          `/api/orders/${order._id}/pay`,
          details,
          {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          }
        );
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_SUCCESS', payload: data });
        toast.success('Order is paid');
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
        toast.error(getError(err));
      }
    });
  }
  function onError(err) {
    toast.error(getError(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
      }
    };

    if (!userInfo) {
      return navigate('/login');
    }
    if (
      !order._id ||
      successPay ||
      (order._id && order._id !== orderId)
    ) {
      fetchOrder();
      if (successPay) {
        dispatch({ type: 'PAY_RESET' });
      }
    } else {
      const loadPaypalScript = async () => {
        const { data: clientId } = await axios.get('/api/keys/paypal', {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        paypalDispatch({
          type: 'resetOptions',
          value: {
            'client-id': clientId,
            currency: 'EUR',
          },
        });
        paypalDispatch({ type: 'setLoadingStatus', value: 'pending' });
      };
      loadPaypalScript();
    }
  }, [
    order,
    userInfo,
    orderId,
    navigate,
    paypalDispatch,
    successPay,
  ]);

  
  

  return loading ? (
    <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
  ) : error ? (
    <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Order {orderId}</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="my-3">Order {orderId}</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Personal Data</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Name:</strong> {order.personalData.fullName} {order.personalData.familieName}<br />
                <strong>Address: </strong> {order.personalData.address},
                <strong>Email :</strong>{order.personalData.email} <br />
                <strong>Birthday :</strong>{order.personalData.birthday}<br />
                <strong>Telefon :</strong>{order.personalData.telefon}<br />
                
                &nbsp;
              </Card.Text>
             
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Payment</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Method:</strong> {order.paymentMethod}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isPaid ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Paid at {order.paidAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Paid</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Items</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                {order.orderItems.map((item) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={item._id}>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                      <Col md={6}>
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                        ></img>{' '}
                        <Link to={`/car/${item.model}`}>{item.mark}</Link>
                      </Col>
                      
                      <Col md={3}>${item.pricePerHour}</Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Order Summary</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
               
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <strong> Order Total</strong>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>$ {carOrderInfo.totalAmount}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                {!order.isPaid && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                  
                   {isPending ? (
                    <LoadingBox />
                   ) :
                   (
                    <div>
                        <PayPalButtons
                        createOrder={createOrder}
                        onApprove={onApprove}
                        onError={onError}
                        ></PayPalButtons>
                    </div>
                   )
                   }
                   {loadingPay && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
                
                
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**orderModel.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    orderItems: [
      {
        model: { type: String, required: true },
        mark: { type: String, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        pricePerHour: { type: Number, required: true },
        car: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Car',
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    personalData: {
      email: {type: String, required: true},
      fullName: { type: String, required: true },
      familieName: {type: String, reqired: true},
      birthday: {type: String, required: true},
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      telefon: {type: Number, required: true}
    },
    paymentMethod: { type: String, required: true },
    paymentResult: {
      id: String,
      status: String,
      update_time: String,
      email_address: String,
    },
    carOrderInfo: {
      totalAmount: { type: Number },
    },
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    isPaid: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    paidAt: { type: Date },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
export default Order;
```

**orderRouters.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import Order from '../models/orderModel.js';

import { isAuth, isAdmin } from '../utils.js';

const orderRouter = express.Router();

orderRouter.get(
  '/',
  isAuth,
  isAdmin,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const orders = await Order.find().populate('user', 'name');
    res.send(orders);
  })
);

orderRouter.post(
  '/',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const newOrder = new Order({
      orderItems: req.body.orderItems.map((x) => ({ ...x, car: x._id })),
      personalData: req.body.personalData,
      paymentMethod: req.body.paymentMethod,
      carOrderInfo: req.body.carOrderInfo,
      user: req.user._id,
    });

    const order = await newOrder.save();
    res.status(201).send({ message: 'New Order Created', order });
  })
);

orderRouter.get(
    '/:id',
    isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id);
      if (order) {
        res.send(order);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order Not Found' });
      }
    })
  );

  orderRouter.put(
    '/:id/pay',
    isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate(
        'user',
        'email name'
      );
      if (order) {
        order.isPaid = true;
        order.paidAt = Date.now();
        order.paymentResult = {
          id: req.body.id,
          status: req.body.status,
          update_time: req.body.update_time,
          email_address: req.body.email_address,
        };
  
        const updatedOrder = await order.save();
        res.send({ message: 'Order Paid', order: updatedOrder });
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order Not Found' });
      }
    })
  );

export default orderRouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in the createOrder function somehow, I'm not sure where it's going wrong. Do some basic debugging of it.

More importantly, actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated and should not be used in any new integration.

See the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) for a non-react example that creates and captures from the backend.  The [integration builder](https://developer.paypal.com/integration-builder/) also has sample react code if you prefer that.